# if statement in html (based on search query)

Tags: python, html, django

I have got a page that displays some content, but I would like to remove the content after a serach query and display the results. I believe that there should be two if statements, one for the current content (if not searching display this) and other one (if searching display other content and hide previous one).

views.py

```
def HomeView(request):
  item_list = Item.objects.all()
  query = request.GET.get('q')
  if query:
    item_list = Item.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
  paginator = Paginator(item_list, 10)

  page = request.GET.get('page')

  try:
      items = paginator.page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
      items = paginator.page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
      items = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

  context = {
      'items': items

  }
  return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

What would I have to put inside the html template to get this to work?

Made something like this, but doesnt work:

```
class BikeView(ListView):
  model = Item
  paginate_by = 10
  template_name = "bikes.html"

  def search(request):
      query = request.GET.get('q')
      if query:
          item_list = Item.objects.all()
          item_list = Item.objects.filter(title__icontains=query)
          context = {
              'items': item_list
          }
          return render(request, "bikes.html", context)
```

Comment: put `{% for x in items %} {{ x }} {% endfor %}` to genterate HTML with results. But it may need some HTML to format it as `<table>` or `<ul>`. Read documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: I know that, but the results are always visible, I want them visible only when I search

Comment: then put all in current `if query:` and don't generate `items` in `context` when there is no query.

Comment: I edited the post with the code, but now the context is not displaying at all

Comment: But in your `HomeView`view you are always returning items. Literally for every cases. You're saying: If there's a page in the query parameter, then return the items for that page. If there's no page in the query parameter, the return the first page. And lastly if there's an empty page, return the last page available. In conclusion, you're always returning items.